# Export selected rows to Excel from table

Tags: jquery, excel, grails, html-table

I am having data in table. There is an checkbox in each row . I want checked rows to be exported to excel file when user click export button.

Here is my code(GSP):

```
<div id="downloadExcelPopup" style="display: none">
    <div id="" class="newserial_popup1"
        style="width: 80%; height: 70%; float:left; ">
        <div class="newbrand">
            <div
                style="background: #ff9900; width: 100%; float: left; padding: 15px;">
                <h3 style="float: left; width: 80%; margin: 0px; color: #ffffff;">Export to Excel</h3>

                <button class="close md-close cancelDownload" aria-hidden="true"
                    data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Ã—</button>

            </div>
            <div class="form-horizontal group-border-dashed"
                style="border-bottom: 1px solid #E5E5E5; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <div class="modal-body form"
                    style="clear: both; padding: 15px 0px 0px 0px;">
<div class="content" >

                        <div class="table-responsive" id="clienttrievent">
                            <table class="table table-bordered" id="datatable3" >
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th><g:checkBox name="myCheckbox" id="selectall" value="${false}" /></th>
                                        <th>Company Name</th>
                                        <th>ROC No</th>
                                        <th>Contact Address</th>
                                        <th>Contact No</th>

                                        <th>E-Mail</th>
                                        <th>Status</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody id="clienttable">
                                    <g:each in="${clientyeardetailsInstanceList}" status="i" var="customerInstance">
                                            <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even gradeC' : 'odd gradeX'}">

                                                <td><g:checkBox name="myCheckbox1" class="case" value="${false}" /></td>
<td>${customerInstance?.client?.companyname}</td>
<td>${customerInstance?.client?.registerno}</td>
<td>${customerInstance?.client?.companyaddress}</td>
<td>${customerInstance?.client?.contactno}</td>
<td>${customerInstance?.client?.email}</td>
<td>${(customerInstance?.client?.clientstatus) == 'on' ? 'ACTIVE' : 'INACTIVE'}</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </g:each>


                                </tbody>
                            </table>

                        </div>
<input type="button" onclick="tableToExcel('datatable3', 'W3C Example Table')" value="Export to Excel">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-flat md-close cancelDownload"
                data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</g:form>

    <script>
    $("#selectall").click(function () {
        var checkAll = $("#selectall").prop('checked');
            if (checkAll) {
                $(".case").prop("checked", true);
            } else {
                $(".case").prop("checked", false);
            }
        });
    var tableToExcel = (function() {
      var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
        , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
        , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
        , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
      return function(table, name) {
        if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
        var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
        window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
      }
    })()
    </script>
```

Please guide me to add the code for :

1. If all rows selected, download full table to excel.
2. Download selected rows alone to excel.

Comment: what is the actual problem then?  what have you tried?

Comment: Using the above code, i can export the whole table data. but not the specific row that i select in checkbox.

Comment: Can you plz help me @cfrick ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Export to [Excel plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/export) for Grails. So, once you set that up, you can call a function in your controller that will automatically export all your rows from the table to excel. However, since you want only some rows to be exported, you can send back the IDs of your rows to the controller function, which can create a criteria query based on only the selected IDs, and that will automatically be exported to Excel.

Comment: Ya thank you! Ill try this. hope it will help me to get the output as expected.

Comment: Can u share the code or any links how to get the id of the row and controller function to write the query plz? Am new for grails and struggling with how to proceed further.